# Reading a PDF file from psql database

Tags: pdf, backbone.js, base64, psql, koa

I'm working on a Backbone project coupled with a koa/node backend that reads on a psql database. I setted a get route that is supposed to point to PDF files, and I was expecting to obtain base64 encrypted strings for each of them. I got this object instead:

```
{"0":37,"1":80,"2":68,"3":70,"4":45,"5":49,"6":46,"7":51,"8":10,"9":37,"10":196,"11":229,"12":242,"13":229,"14":235,"15":167,"16":243,"17":160,"18":208,"19":196,"20":198,"21":10,"22":52,"23":32,"24":48,"25":32,"26":111,"27":98,"28":106,"29":10,"30":60,"31":60,"32":32,"33":47,"34":76,"35":101,"36":110,"37":103,"38":116,"39":104,"40":32,"41":53,"42":32,"43":48,"44":32,"45":82,"46":32,"47":47,"48":70,"49":105,"50":108,"51":116,"52":101,"53":114,"54":32,"55":47,"56":70,"57":108,"58":97,"59":116,"60":101,"61":68,"62":101,"63":99,"64":111,"65":100,"66":101,"67":32,"68":62,"69":62,"70":10,"71":115,"72":116,"73":114,"74":101,"75":97,"76":109,"77":10,"78":120,"79":1,"80":149,"81":86,"82":203,"83":114,"84":26,"85":89,"86":12,"87":221,"88":247,"89":87,"90":104,"91":118,"92":120,"93":145,"94":235... }
```

Has anyone ever seen this kind of representation for a PDF file? How can I get this data back as a regular PDF file?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a pretty broken way to get things out of a database. Your object is a pair of {position: byte}, as Python hints the first items are part of a PDF header:

```
>>> [chr(i) for i in [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 51]]
['%', 'P', 'D', 'F', '-', '1', '.', '3']
```

Since you did not specify any libraries/code, I can’t provide any direct advice, but you should check what your database really contains (this should be a BLOB of binary data, not base64 or crazy JSON) and how to get the raw binary data out of your database using the libraries of your choice.

Comment: This is what the database is supposed to contain (that's the very same file in the data property): 
    {"id": 0, "result": [{"data": {"base64": "JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp/Og0MTGCjQgMCBvYmo...3RhcnR4cmVmCjE2MD‌​gwNQolJUVPRgo=\n", "class": "bytes"}, "id": 27}]} I'm using the tryton-model library, that handles the database reading.